# Laravel 4: Inject view model into Controller

Tags: php, laravel-4, dependency-injection

I am just starting to learn Laravel and started with the basics on [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch/episodes/13). In this [episode 13](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch/episodes/13) it shows howto inject the `User` model into the `UserController` with the use of the constructor.

But when I try to inject the `View` and `Input` model using the same technique I run into some errors like:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR) 
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::make()

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR) 
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::all()
```

When I inject the `Redirect` model it just works like the `User` model. Could somebody explain to me why `View` and `Input` don't work? And howto fix this?

**UserController:**

NOTE: I commented the lines out that didn't work and threw the errors, the lines like `$this->view->make();`

```
class UserController extends \BaseController {

    protected $user, $redirect, $view, $input;

    public function __construct(User $user, Redirect $redirect, View $view, Input $input)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->view = $view;
        $this->input = $input;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = $this->user->all();
        return View::make('users.index', ['users' => $users]);
        // TODO: Why does below not work?
        // return $this->view->make('users.index', ['users' => $users]);
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for creating a net
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('users.create');
        // TODO: Why does below not work?
        // return $this->view->make('users.create');
    }


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        $input = Input::all();
        // TODO: Why does below not work?
        // $input = $this->input->all();

        if ( ! $this->user->fill($input)->isValid() )
        {
            return $this->redirect->back()->withInput()->withErrors($this->user->errors);
        }

        $this->user->save();

        return $this->redirect->route('users.index');
    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $user = $this->user->find($id);
        return View::make('users.show', ['user' => $user]);
        // TODO: Why does below not work?
        // return $this->view->make('users.show', ['user' => $user]);
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can not inject Laravel facades into your controller. Every facade in Laravel has some adnotation about what class you should use if you want to inject it. For example:

```
/**
 * @see \Illuminate\View\Factory
 */
class View extends Facade {

    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'view'; }

}
```

Like you see there is an adnotation `@see` which let you know that if you want to inject it to controller you should use `Illuminate\View\Factory`.